# Ms.Access query in vb.net select all from tbl1 and only 1 column from tbl2

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have 2 tables:

- `tbl1(ID, Name, Sex, OrderDate)`
- `tbl2(OrderDate, OrderCode)`

I try to display all data from `tbl1 (ID, Name, Sex, OrderDate)` and **only** one column from `tbl2(OrderCode)`.

I have tried this

```
SELECT tbl1.*, tbl2.OrderCode FROM tbl1, tbl2;
```

but it shows duplicate data. like this

[image: Like this]

I have search a while but only see query of mySQL where they use `join` but it appears syntax error clause.

I want it appears like this **ID Name Sex OrderDate OrderCode**
OrderCode is autoNumber Random which is why I put it in other table since Access not allow 2 autoNumber in same table

Comment: your query returning `cross join` of both table try to use `left outer join` and `distinct` keyword

Comment: Please show us your expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my expect outcome is **ID Name Sex OrderDate OrderCode**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two tables as following:

[image]

and then use this query

```
select t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Sex, t2.OrderDate, t2.OrderCode from 
Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Comment: which is duplicated ?

Comment: Show us your _exact_ output, with all columns, clearly showing how you want to handle duplicates.

Comment: please see updated answer, and explain desired output clearly

Comment: @Smart how about OrderCode (it is an autonumber - Random) .. my desired output is **ID Name Sex OrderDate OrderCode**

Comment: oh it works now ... thank so much ... i can choose either t1.OrderDate or t2.OrderDate right?

Comment: yeah, you can select one instead of two dates

Comment: @Smart pls answer this: how about ID ... because t1.ID is autonumber but t2.ID is number ... is it ok for them to have different value/number?

Comment: How do you insert record ? do you insert into table1 and table2 at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a CROSS JOIN which results in a cartesian product

You should JOIN on the field that is common in the 2 tables to limit the rows returned.

In your case the only field I see on both tables is OrderDate, and that's a bit weird.

Try this

```
SELECT tbl1.*, tbl2.OrderCode FROM tbl1, tbl2 WHERE tbl1.OrderDate=tbl2.OrderDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your table  tbl1(ID, Name, Sex, OrderDate)
tbl2(OrderDate, OrderCode) doesnt have a Relationship, You Must Relate This Two Table Before You can Select Columns..
Try This:
New Table:
tbl1(ID, Name, Sex, OrderDate)
tbl2(ID,OrderDate, OrderCode)
tbl1.Id Is Primary Key and Tbl2.ID is the foreign Key
And i Will Select All Columns In Tbl1 and one column in tbl2
(Regardless of Case Restrictions)

`Select tbl1.Id,tbl1.name,tbl1.sex,tbl1.Orderdate,tbl2.orderdate from tbl1,tbl2 where tbl1.id=tbl2.id`

Comment: but tbl1.ID (autonumber) is not the same as tbl2.ID (number)

Comment: it is working nicely...but instead I want to use to INNER JOIN since I dont want to mess up with relationship. Thank so much !

Comment: Great.. Hope Your Doing Well.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get a result that has a relationship with two tables, that means you want to use Join.

you can also use distinct when you have redundant result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl1.*, tbl2.OrderCode FROM tbl1, tbl2;
```